# How to open the event handler to a link button in a WebForm (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, button, webforms, click, eventhandler

I did my first app but I am having hard time to find the event handler to my link button which I have created. I connected my gridview to my SQL file, did validations all I have to do now is to "teach" the Insert button to insert the new row to my SQL server file.

I opened all the folders in the Solution Explorer but could not find Webform.aspx.cs (I guess this should be the file name).
I read somewhere that I need to go on the code of the link button then press twice the TAB, but it did not work.
This is the link button that I am talking about:

```
<asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup ="INSERT" ID="lbInsert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
```

[image]

And I am looking for such a file:

[image]

Comment: Post your code not as a code formatted text block. Don't post a link to an image of code

Comment: It would be Webform.aspx.vb for VB.NET. The .cs extension is for C#.

Answer (score 0):

In your previous response you pasted the following code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup ="INSERT" ID="lbInsert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
```

which is missing the OnClick property. Please ensure the following code is present

```
OnClick="lbInsert_Click"
```

If you have the design view open, double clicking on the LinkButton should take you directly to the event in the code behind and If no such event exists, it will create it for you.